# How To Obtain Argentinian Visa For a Philippine Passport Holder in Brasil

Tags: visas, brazil, argentina, filipino-citizens

I am currently in Brasil and I have travelled South America for a year using my Philippine passport. My next stop will be Argentina and I'd like to ask if I can obtain an Argentinian visa here in Brasil? Please take note that
**I am not a Brasilian citizen nor a resident. I am only travelling here**.

I was also here in Brasil last year and I was able to obtain a visa for Panama for 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

You have to contact your local Argentinian embassy / consulate in Brazil who will determine if you're eligible to get an Argentinian visa.

I'm speculating here but given that you're a non-resident in Brazil, the Argentinian consulate MAY ask you to obtain a visa from your home country, the Philippines.

I understand that you obtained a visa for Panama while being a non-resident in Brazil, but each country has its own rules when it comes to issuing visas.

Your best bet is to contact your local consulate, or even email them, and ask them if you qualify.

Answer (score 1):

For Philippine passport holders, it is possible to get a visa for Argentina while in Brazil. I did this before and it can be expedited same day process. People in the Argentina embassy in Brasilia were very helpful.